# How important is the order of the conditional in the ($\epsilon$, $\delta$)-definition of the limit? Would it matter if it is a biconditional?

Tags: calculus, limits

So we're looking at the ($\epsilon$, $\delta$)-definition of the limit in class and I am kind of confused, because the teacher says one thing but the books say another. Teacher says that $\lim_{x \to p} f(x) = L$ if:

$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(0 < |x - p| < \delta \iff |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)$

Now I went into the book, and it actually says something similar but different, it says that for the limit to exist and be equal to $L$ we must have:

$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(0 < |x - p| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)$

The teacher is very adamant that it is a double implication and we need to prove it from one way to the other and vice versa. I have several questions. Firstly, what would even change if we invert the conditional on the definition of limit that the books have? Say we change it to this:

$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(|f(x) - L| < \epsilon \implies 0 < |x - p| < \delta)$

My intuition tells me that if the limit exists in the original definition, then it will also exists on the converse one and vice versa, and thus they are equivalent. But if this is true, then why do books only tell you one version of the definition of the limit and not the converse version? My last question is, assuming the converse is equivalent, then what's the point of having a biconditional version? Wouldn't that just be extra work for no reason?

Comment: A biconditional would force *all* values of $f(x)$ near $L$ to occur near $a$. The constant function $f(x)=L$ would not satisfy the definition, since for every $a$, for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ and every $\delta\gt0$, there exist $x$ for which $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$ but $|x-a|\gt\delta$. The biconditional is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: For what it's worth, I second the comment of @ArturoMagidin.  Bluntly, the teacher is mistaken.  You can consider printing this page out and showing it to the teacher.  I have never seen anyone define the existence of a limit as a biconditional.  You might ask the teacher to show you the book that the teacher got the definition from.

Comment: (And the constant function shows you why the last displayed formula also cannot be correct. Other examples are periodic functions that are not constant, like $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$.) Intuitively, the limit is about what $f$ does near (but not at) $a$. Not about *where* $f$ lands near $L$.

Comment: ...and it would even fail for one-to-one *continuous* functions, such as $f(x)=x$, since $|f(a)-a|=0\lt \epsilon$, but $a$ does not satisfy $0\lt|a-a|\lt\delta$... So there goes the definition of continuity using limits.

Answer (score 1):

The statement with the biconditional is definitely *not* the correct definition of limit. Your instructor is just wrong.

Let me write the two statements so we can refer to them:

$$\begin{align*}
(\forall \epsilon\gt 0)(\exists \delta\gt 0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta\implies |f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon) \tag{*}\\
(\forall \epsilon\gt 0)(\exists \delta\gt 0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta\iff |f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon)\tag{**}
\end{align*}
$$
$(*)$ is the usual definition of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$. And $(**)$ is what your instructor is giving instead.

Statement $(**)$ is way too restrictive. And it includes too many things that are not part of the idea of limit. You are correct that a function $f$, point $a$, and number $L$ that satisfy $(**)$ will satisfy $(*)$, but the converse need not hold.

The idea of "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is equal to $L$" is that we can guarantee that the values of $f$ will be as close as we want to $L$ for every $x$ that is "sufficiently close" (but not equal) to $a$. It does not care what happens at $a$, and it doesn't care what happens "far" from $a$.

The biconditional, however, asserts that, in addition, the *only* way for $f(x)$ to be near $L$ is for $x$ to be near, but not be equal, to $a$. That is antithetical to the notion of limit, which does not care what happens far from $a$.

As I noted in my comment, definition $(**)$ would imply that the constant function $f(x)=L$ does not have a limit at any point $a$. For given any $a$, any $\epsilon\gt 0$, and any $\delta\gt 0$, you can find $x$ with $|f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$ but $|x-a|\gt\delta$ (just take $x=a+2\delta$) So the implication
$$|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon\implies 0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta$$
does not hold. I don't know about you, but if my definition of limit tells me that a *constant function* doesn't have a limit *anywhere*... then it doesn't seem like it is a very good function.

In fact, definition $(**)$ can only work if $f$ is ***not*** defined at $a$! For suppose that $f$ is defined at $a$. If $f(a)=L$, take $\epsilon=1$, and if $f(a)\neq L$, then take $\epsilon = 2|f(a)-L|$. Then $x=a$ satisfies $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$, but does not satisfy $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta$ for *any* $\delta\gt 0$ (since it does not satisfy $0\lt |x-a|$). That's also a problem, since we are supposed to *not care* what happens at $a$ when we take the limit, and this definition forces $f$ to not be defined at $a$. So, not function whose domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$ can have a limit at *any* point. Also a bad thing.

So... when does a function satisfy $(**)$ for a given $a$ and a given $L$? Well, it's hard to pinpoint; but here are a bunch of conditions such a function must satisfy:

1. $f$ is defined in an open interval around $a$, but *not* at $a$.
2. The limit in the usual sense $(*)$ exists and is equal to $L$, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$.
3. If $y$ is in the domain of $f$, and $z$ is strictly between $y$ and $a$, then $|f(z)-L|\leq |f(y)-L|$.
4. If $x$ is in the domain of $f$, then every point strictly between $x$ and $a$ is in the domain of $f$.
5. For all $r\gt 0$, if $a+r$ is in the domain of $f$, then so is $a-r$, and $|f(a+r)-L|=|f(a-r)-L|$.
6. For every $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exist $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-L|\geq \epsilon$.

Indeed, assume $f$ satisfies $(**)$ relative to $a$ and $L$. We already noted that $f$ cannot be defined at $a$ for $(**)$ to hold. And the definition requires that there be a $\gamma\gt 0$ such that if $|x-a|\lt\gamma$, then $f(x)$ is defined; otherwise, for every $\delta\gt 0$ there would be an $x$ with $0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta$, but $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$ would not hold, as it would not even make sense. So 1 holds.

We also know that $(**)$ implies $(*)$, so we need the usual limit to exist, yielding 2.

To show that 3 is necessary, suppose that $f$, $L$, and $a$ satisfy $(**)$, and that $y\lt z\lt a$ are such that $|f(y)-L|\lt |f(z)-L|$ (the case $a\lt z\lt y$ is similar). Let $\epsilon$ be such that $|f(y)-L|\lt \epsilon\lt |f(z)-L|$. If $\delta$ satisfies $(**)$ relative to $\epsilon$, then it must be the case that $0\lt |y-a|\lt \delta$. Therefore, $0<|z-a|\lt\delta$. But we also have $|f(z)-L|\gt\epsilon$, which contradicts the *forward* direction of $(**)$. Thus, 3 is necessary for $(**)$ to be satisfied.

To show 4 is necessary, let $x$ be in the domain of $f$; pick $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$. Then the $\delta$ corresponding to this $\epsilon$ must satisfy $0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta$. If $y$ is strictly between $x$ and $a$, then $0\lt|y-a|\lt\epsilon$, and therefore we must have $|f(y)-L|\lt\epsilon$; in particular, $f$ must be defined at $y$. This gives $4$.

To get 5 let $r\gt 0$ be such that $f$ is defined at $a+r$, and pick $\epsilon$ with $|f(a+r)-L|\lt\epsilon$. As above, if $\delta$ satisfies $(**)$ relative to this $\epsilon$, then we have $0\lt|(a+r)-a|=r\lt \delta$, and therefore $0|\lt|(a-r)-a|\lt\delta$; therefore, we must have $|f(a-r)-L|\lt\epsilon$, and in particular $f$ is defined at $a-r$. If $|f(a-r)-L|\neq|f(a+r)-L|$, pick $\epsilon\gt 0$ so that exactly one of $|f(a-r)-L|$ and $|f(a+r)-L|$ are strictly less than $\epsilon$, say $|f(a-r)-L|\lt \epsilon$. Then the backward implication tells us that we must have $r\lt\delta$, cut in that case, we have $0\lt |(a+r)-a|\lt\delta$, and therefore the forward implication gives $|f(a+r)-L|\lt\epsilon$, contradicting our choice of $\epsilon$. This shows 5.

Finally, note that if $6$ does not hold, then there is an $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that for every $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we have $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$; then for every $\delta\gt 0$ there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$ but $|x-a|\geq\delta$, contradicting $(**)$.

As you can see, that would mean a lot of functions don't have limits at a lot of points! That makes $(**)$ really useless.